# Symfony2: Can't launch after generating bundle

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, terminal, mamp

I just created a Symfony2 project by generating this with Terminal (OSX).

I generated the following things:

- Bundle Namespace: SG/FOBundle
- Bundle Name: SGFOBundle
- Configuration Format: YML

All other settings are default (yes, yes, yes -> You can now start using the generated code!)

--

When I added the folder as a PHP project in Netbeans and upon launching (MAMP is active), I only get the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method SocialGEO\FOBundle\SocialGEOFOBundle::getName() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/socialgeo/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 798

I can't find any solution to this either on Google or the Symfony website.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you see SocialGEO\FOBundle\SocialGEOFOBundle::getName()?

php app/console cache:clear may help.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. :) I cleared the cache twice. First manually (deleted the folder in Finder: app/cache) and then by your method. Still getting the same error though...

Comment: I suppose it's an error of my computer itself. When using the default AcmeBundle, everything works as it should.